# Which variables do I have to consider for calculating the stunting prevalence confidence interval?

Tags: rstudio, survey, confidence-interval

I am analyzing the Association of the Global Gender Gap Score and child anthropometric failures(with Rstudio). For that purpose I calculated the z-scores for the anthropometric failures for instance stunting and then I calculated the prevalence of stunting in that respective country. Data for calculating child anthropometric failure I got from DHS, and the z-scores were calculated in R with the help of the package z-scorer. Now I am struggling with calculating the confidence intervals for stunting prevalence.

I used the package "survey" for complex survey designs.

library(survey)

## Complex sample design parameters

`DHSdesign<-svydesign(id=CI_sample$v021, strata=CI_sample$v023, weights=CI_sample$wt, data=CI_sample, nest=TRUE)`

## tabulate indicator by region

`svyby(~stuntprev, ~CountryID, DHSdesign, svymean, vartype=c("se","ci"))`

What R gave me then was:

````
     ```CountryID stuntprev      se  ci_l  ci_u
 NM07      NM07     0.308        0   0.308 0.308
 NM13      NM13     0.225        0   0.225 0.225```
````

For instance the stunting prevalence in Namibia in 2007 was 30.8% the lower and upper bound are also 30.8%, so how should I change the command to make it work?

Comment: hi, that sort of looks like you've got only one record in your dataset or at least that they're all the same..  maybe provide more detail about `CI_sample` here or use a public data set?